# Is GLib's GAsyncQueue guaranteed to be FIFO?

Tags: c, queue, gnome, glib

Documentation of GLib's [GAsyncQueue](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/2.36/glib-Asynchronous-Queues.html) does not state what the order of the pushed/poped elements is. From my testing, it seems to be FIFO which is exactly what I need. But is this guaranteed on all target platforms?

Comment: If it were a LIFO, it would be stack, not queue. I think you are pretty safe assuming FIFO. I have newer heard of LIFO queues (not counting deques).

Answer (score 1):

It works according the FIFO principle (as it is already implied with the name Queue) - there is no additional sorting or mixing applied.